# Call Scala generic method from Java

Tags: java, scala

How can I call the following Scala method from Java?

```
def mult[A,B: ClassTag,C: ClassTag](rdd1:RDD[A], rdd2:RDD[B])(implicit multiplier: Multiplier[A,B,C]): RDD[C] =
    rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(p => multiplier.multiply(p._1, p._2))
```

Is it possible? Eclipse isn't giving me any help from its autocomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh.  Must you?  The B and C ClassTags are added to the list of implicit parameters (before the explicit ones), so you can add appropriate ones generated with the `scala.reflect.ClassTag` object.  But it's going to be ugly.

Something like (untested):

```
mult(rdd1, rdd2, scala.reflect.ClassTag.apply(B.class), scala.reflect.ClassTag.apply(C.class), myMult);
```